# modifying filter method using collectors.groupingby

Tags: java, collectors

I'm reading from a .txtfile and then I'm trying to group employees based on a salary range. Then showing the number of employees and the average salary of that group. What I've tried so far is, using the list.stream().filter method. However, I need to group them using the collectors.groupingBy, and a collectors.summarizingDouble() and collectors.average() method. But I can't seem to do it. Here's what I've done so far, 
the getSalary method:

```
public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return Salary;
    }
```

the driver class:

```
  Map<Object, Long> avgSalary=
                         employee_list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(emp->emp.getSalary().doubleValue() < 30000, Collectors.counting()));
                                  
                         Set<Entry<Object, Long>> entrySet = avgSalary.entrySet();
                                  
                         for (Entry<Object, Long> entry : entrySet) 
                         {
                             System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
                         }
```

I'd really appreciate some help to replace the filter method with collectors.groupuingBy(). The output can be like:
**<30000 : 1 : avg salary : 23000** 
**40000-50000 : 2 : avg salary : 44000**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Collectors.summarizingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) and establish each group clearly:

```
Map<String, DoubleSummaryStatistics> result = employee_list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(emp -> 
             emp.getSalary().doubleValue() < 30000 ?
                 "<30000" :
             emp.getSalary().doubleValue() < 40000 ?
                 "30000-40000" :
             emp.getSalary().doubleValue() < 50000 ?
                 "40000-50000" :
                 ">50000",
             Collectors.summarizingDouble(emp -> emp.getSalary().doubleValue())));
```

Then, simply access each group by key, i.e. `"40000-50000"` and get its statistics:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats40k50k = result.get("40000-50000");
```

All statistics for each group are collected to [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) objects, from where you can get i.e. the average:

```
double avg40k50k = stats40k50k == null ? 0.0 : stats40k50k.getAverage();
```

Comment: but I'm getting errors, I had to change the Map<String ,DoubleSummaryStatistics> to  Map<Object ,DoubleSummaryStatistics> as eclipse suggested.  and the emp.getSalary is also showing an error saying that the type expression must be a functional interface

Comment: the above part works, but in the very last line, `double avg40k50k = stats40k50k == null ? "0.0" : stats40k50k.getAverage();` it shows an error below 0.0 which says can't convert from string to double